# Timer App similar to 4.2 clock alarms

Tags: android, timer, alarm, timepicker

I want to do something like the alarms in the 4.2 clock.

But instead of alarms I want to use it for different timers.

Enter a name and min:sec, click + (for example) and it creates a card like element (not even the pulldown or other stuff) which I can click to start the timer or long press to delete.

Is there an easy way to add this or do I have to create it from scratch?

Also the new timepicker dialog is kinda nice but its not part of Android right (Could only find the scrollwheel picker)? So have to create something similar myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mimic features of the stock app, you should look at the code itself.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/

Comment: This seems to be the 2.2 AlarmClock.